# Surjectivity of colimit maps for topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits

From this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8667/on-limits-and-colimits) and to (co)completness of the category **Top** of topological spaces and continuous functions we know that for any diagram $B_i$ and an object $A$ in **Top**, there are natural maps of sets:$\newcommand{\colim}{\operatorname{colim}}$

1. $\colim C(A,B_i) \to C(A, \colim B_i)$
2. $\colim C(B_i,A) \to C(\lim B_i, A)$

For any topological spaces, equip $C(X,Y)$ with the compact-open topology; then $C(X,Y)$ is itself a topological space.  When is the map of $1$ (resp. $2$) a *surjective*(or at-least has dense range) continuous map?

*Related:* [This post on the dual question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289851/colimits-limits-and-mapping-spaces) and [this post on naturality of the aforementioned maps.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8667/on-limits-and-colimits)

Comment: I guess it rarely happens, but for example, if the diagram is filtered and A is compact, 1 can be homeomorphism.

Comment: Oh, would you happen to have a reference to this?  I'd like to read-up on it.

Comment: No, I don't, but the idea would be, if A is compact, and we have a filtered colimit, and, let's say, the colimit of "good" injective maps (whatever that means), for any map from A to the colimit, the image has to be contained in finite stage.  And, if A is not a compact, you can take $B_i$'s to be compact approximation, in which case one sees clearly that the map can't be surjective.